# read .txt file off the web and convert it to data frame

Tags: r, csv

How can I read this file on the [a .txt file on the web](https://www.nass.usda.gov/Data_and_Statistics/County_Data_Files/Frequently_Asked_Questions/county_list.txt) and convert the content to .csv file? (either python or R, both works.)

```
page = readLines('https://www.nass.usda.gov/Data_and_Statistics/County_Data_Files/Frequently_Asked_Questions/county_list.txt')
page <- page[13:4079]
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 4067))
col_names = c("state", "district", "county", "state_county", "history")
colnames(df) <- col_names
for (row_count in 1:4067){
    df[row_count, 1] = unlist(strsplit(page[row_count], " "))[1]
    df[row_count, 2] = unlist(strsplit(page[row_count], " "))[4]
    df[row_count, 3] = unlist(strsplit(page[row_count], " "))[7]
    df[row_count, 4] = unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(page[row_count], 
           " "))[10], "\t"))[1]
df[row_count, 5] = unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(page[row_count], 
           " "))[10], "\t"))[7]}
```

some of the names on the fourth columns are consist of more than one word, and the space between fourth and fifth columns are of different size, and that makes my code dysfunctional!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this help?

```
library(tidyverse)
url <- "https://www.nass.usda.gov/Data_and_Statistics/County_Data_Files/Frequently_Asked_Questions/county_list.txt"
df <- read_lines(url, skip = 12) %>%
    data.frame(col = .) %>%
    separate(col, into = paste0("X", 1:5), sep = "\\s{2,}", extra = "drop") %>%
    na.omit()
head(df)
#  X1 X2  X3         X4 X5
#1 01 00 000    Alabama  1
#2 01 10 033    Colbert  1
#3 01 10 057    Fayette  2
#4 01 10 059   Franklin  1
#5 01 10 075      Lamar  2
#6 01 10 077 Lauderdale  1
```

Explanation:

1. Read file line-by-line with `readr::read_lines`
2. Store entries in column `col` of `data.frame`
3. Separate entries on any >=2 whitespace characters (spaces, tabs) in a row and store in columns `X1...X5`
4. Remove `NA`s

Comment: Fantastic! I found a way around this, did it brute force till waiting for a response!
How did you come up with this! I have to learn this!

Comment: I tried coming up with a more direct method to parse the file using e.g. `read_delim` but failed;-) `read_lines` (or base R's `readLines`) allows for a lot of flexibility when it comes to custom parsing of text data. `tidyr::separate` is a really nice and useful function to separate entries into multiple fields based on a regexp.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `base` solution

```
dataStart <- min(which(grepl('^\\d+\\s+\\d+\\s+\\d+\\s+\\w+\\s+\\d$', page, perl = TRUE)))
pageDat <- page[dataStart:length(page)]
pageDat <- gsub("\\s{2,}", ";", pageDat, perl = TRUE)
pageDat <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(pageDat, split = ";"))
# yields
head(pageDat)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]         [,5]
[1,] "01" "00" "000" "Alabama"    "1" 
[2,] "01" "10" "033" "Colbert"    "1" 
[3,] "01" "10" "057" "Fayette"    "2" 
[4,] "01" "10" "059" "Franklin"   "1" 
[5,] "01" "10" "075" "Lamar"      "2" 
[6,] "01" "10" "077" "Lauderdale" "1"
```

where `page` is as given above.

Answer (score 2):

Another base solution, more wordy than @nate.edwinton's (comments in the source):

```
# read the file as fixed field width file
page <- read.fwf( "https://www.nass.usda.gov/Data_and_Statistics/County_Data_Files/Frequently_Asked_Questions/county_list.txt",
    widths = c( 5, 5, 6, 45 ), skip = 12, sep = "^" )
# remove the last line containing NAs
page <- page[ -length( page[,1] ), ]
# convert factors to character
page[ , 4 ] <- as.character( page[ , 4 ] )
# the last character of the fourth field contains the history, move it to a separate variable
page[ 5 ] <- substr( page[ , 4 ], nchar( page[ , 4 ] ), nchar( page[ , 4 ] ) )
# set the column names
colnames( page )[] <- c( "state", "district", "county", "state_county", "history" )
# remove the history info from the state_county field
page[ , 4 ] <- gsub( "[12]$", "", page[ , 4 ] )
# get rid of the tabs
page[ , 4 ] <- gsub( "\t", "", page[ , 4 ] )
# format the output as in the original file (may be necessary or not)
page[ , 1 ] <- sprintf( "%02i", page[ , 1 ] )
page[ , 2 ] <- sprintf( "%02i", page[ , 2 ] )
page[ , 3 ] <- sprintf( "%03i", page[ , 3 ] )
```

This give us

```
head( page, 15 )
   state district county          state_county history
1     01       00    000               Alabama       1
2     01       10    033               Colbert       1
3     01       10    057               Fayette       2
4     01       10    059              Franklin       1
5     01       10    075                 Lamar       2
6     01       10    077            Lauderdale       1
7     01       10    079              Lawrence       1
8     01       10    083             Limestone       1
9     01       10    089               Madison       1
10    01       10    093                Marion       1
11    01       10    103                Morgan       1
12    01       10    133               Winston       1
13    01       10    888 D10 Combined Counties       1
14    01       10    999   D10 Northern Valley       1
15    01       20    009                Blount       1
```